# Calculate last third of two Dates in Java

Tags: java, date, time, java.util.date

I am searching for a method to get the last third of two dates.

**first example:**

> Date 1 = 22:00
>
> Date 2 = 01:00 (next day)
>
> calculateLastThird(); (output: 00:00)

**second example:**

> Date 1 = 22:25
>
> Date 2 = 01:45 (next day)
>
> calculateLastThird(); (output: 00:38)

I already know how to get the midpoint between those two dates:

```
Date midpoint = new Date((date1.getTime() + date2.getTime()) / 2);
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead you probably want to use either `LocalTime` or `ZonedDateTime`. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: What you mean by last third of date?

Comment: @HarinderSingh I think it’s easier to understand from the examples. I take it as the point when two thirds of the time between the two have elapsed. From 22 to 1 is three hours, Two thirds is 2 hours, and 2 hours after 22 is 00:00.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Boise");
    ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 12, 26, 22, 0, 0, 0, zone);
    ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 12, 27, 1, 0, 0, 0, zone);
    
    Duration fullElapsedTime = Duration.between(zdt1, zdt2);
    Duration twoThirds = fullElapsedTime.multipliedBy(2).dividedBy(3);
    ZonedDateTime lastThird = zdt1.plus(twoThirds);
    
    System.out.println(lastThird);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 2020-12-27T00:00-07:00[America/Boise]

Three things I like about this code are:

1. It pretty well mimics the way one would do the calculation by hand and how you would explain to someone else which calculation you want at all.
2. It takes any transistion to or from summer time (DST) into account.
3. It leaves the actual calculation to the library methods. It involves no low-level addition or division in your own code.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is the following:

```
Date midpoint = new Date((date1.getTime() + 2 * date2.getTime()) / 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist using `Date`.
It should be a simple math:

1. First, need to calculate the difference between the two dates (in milliseconds).
2. Then get the 2/3 rd of that value and add it to the first date.

```
private static Date calculateLastThird(Date d1, Date d2) { 
        // Calculate time difference in milliseconds 
        long differenceMillis = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        double millisToAdd = (2.0/3.0) * differenceMillis;
        
        Date twoThird = new Date(d1.getTime() + (long) millisToAdd);
        
        return twoThird;
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date date1= sdf1.parse("2020/12/26 22:00:00");
            Date date2= sdf1.parse("2020/12/27 01:00:00");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            System.out.println("Last third: " + sdf2.format(calculateLastThird(date1, date2)));
            
            Date date3= sdf1.parse("2020/12/26 22:25:00");
            Date date4= sdf1.parse("2020/12/27 01:45:00");
            System.out.println("Last third: " + sdf2.format(calculateLastThird(date3, date4)));
            
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }
```

Sample output of above code:

```
Last third: 00:00
Last third: 00:38
```

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Sun, Oracle, and the JCP community have given up on these legacy classes. So should we all. See modern solution in [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65457515/642706).